# Starting with PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell

I start learning Windows PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10, newest version. I use the Microsoft PowerShell documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/

Q1: It is mentioned that you need Windows Management Framework (WMF) 5.1 for Windows PowerShell 5.1 but in Windows 10 PowerShell 5.1 is allready installed by default. So there is no WMF 5.1 needed, or is WMF 5.1 installed in Windows 10? How can I see if WMF is installed and which version?

Q2: There are also Microsoft .NET Framework requirements for Windows PowerShell 5.1: It requires the full installation of Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5. How can I find which version of .NET Framework is installed on my PC? I see there allready is a version 4.8 runtime and 4.8 developer pack. So I think the best I can do is install 4.8 Developer Pack?

The reason is that if I want to use and install packages from the PowerShell Gallery I need the PowerShellGet module and the PowerShellGet module requires .NET Framework 4.5 or above.

Comment: Windows 10 comes with WMF5.1 and the appropriate version of .NET installed (I mean, PowerShell 5.1 is already on the box, right?) :)

Answer (score 0):

To determine the DotNet Framework version you can check the registry or use a 3rd party tool: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed)

For example, you can run this:

`(Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full").Release`

and then check the release table:

```
.NET Framework 4.5      378389
.NET Framework 4.5.1    378675
.NET Framework 4.5.2    379893
.NET Framework 4.6      393295
.NET Framework 4.6.1    394254
.NET Framework 4.6.2    394802
.NET Framework 4.7      460798
.NET Framework 4.7.1    461308
.NET Framework 4.7.2    461808
.NET Framework 4.8      528040
```

Comment: Hi Carlos, yes this was exactly what I was looking for. If I run your line it says 528040 so .NET Framework 4.8 is installed. The link is also usefull, so thank you.

Comment: Good that it helped :)